# read the edge list from a csv file and create a graph with networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, read.csv

Hi everyone I want to read the edge list from a csv file and create a graph with networkx to calculate the betweenness centrality with python. My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
df = pd.read_csv('edges1.csv')
Graphtype = nx.Graph()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, edge_attr='genre_ids', create_using=Graphtype)
centrality = nx.betweenness_centrality(G, normalize=False)
print(centrality)
```

edges1.csv have 97180 row:

```
Surce,Target,genre_ids
Avatar,Violent Night,18
Harry Potter,The Woman King,20
Happy Feet, Froze,23
so on....
```

My code give me error: `KeyError: 'source'`. How can i do?

Comment: I didn't test it but I guess instead of `Surce,Target,genre_ids` in the csv you should put `source,target,genre_ids`, so with an `o` in _source_ and lower case.

Comment: `from_pandas_edgelist` requires valid `source` column, fix your file header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading the data, make sure the column names in `csv` file match the default expected values OR specify the custom names.

If the column names are "Surce,Target,genre_ids" (as in the snippet provided by OP), then the appropriate command is:

```py
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df,
    source="Surce",
    target="Target",
    edge_attr='genre_ids',
    create_using=Graphtype
)
```

See [the docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html).